# Change GPO users with ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gpo

I'm trying to make an ASP.Net Intranet website in c# with a feature that allows an administrator to change what users or computers are assigned to a GPO in our active directory.

I looked at [IGroupPolicyObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa374235%28VS.85%29.aspx), but I couldn't figure out how to use it to change what users are assigned to a GPO.

Can IGroupPolicyObject even do that? If so can someone show me an example of how to do it? If not, does anyone know of a library or extension that does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with AD you must use [Directory Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices(v=vs.110).aspx). I've managed to create users, assign them to groups, change their password, login and etc, but never handled GPO per se... good luck...

Comment: Thanks, that pointed me in the right direction! I'll manually add a group to the GPO, then I'll use this to dynamically add/remove users from it.